# Which libraries are indispensable?

Tags: programming-languages

If you moved to a new programming language, which libraries do you feel must be supported if you're to keep using the language?

I am interested in both specific libraries (eg, bindings for libXYZ should exist) and categories (eg, a regular expression library should exist).

As an extension to this, what are the deal breaker features or design decisions (language level or library level) that would persuade you to switch to another language or to ignore it? Does your current main language support these well? How could they be improved upon?

I am interested to hear what people find most important for their choice of programming language besides syntax, platform support, efficiency and paradigm.

Comment: The libraries that do not implement IDisposable

Comment: What's the point? The libraries we need are the ones that are relevant to the area we work in. If you look hard enough, you're going to find that *everything* is indispensible to someone. This is pretty much the definition of subjective.

Comment: @jalf: No. You can get a lot of work down with just some simple i/o and string functions. See the Unix shell tools. You can rearrange the problem set to fit the tools. But those tools have to be flexible enough to do so.

Comment: @jaff, Sure, we all need specific problem-dependent tools. Perhaps I should have phrased it as what general purpose libraries or what libraries should be part of the standard library... I'm interested to know what libraries which would be of use to the largest group of people should be packaged with a language to ensure its usefulness to as many people as possible. Anything specific then falls outside that and must be provided on a case by case basis, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Strong xUnit-like library.

Webservice support

XML Processing

A database connectivity library

A Networking library

A threading library

A File IO library

In terms of frameworks:

A Rich GUI library

An AJAX library

An application server.

Answer (score 3):

String handling is still essential today. So either the language or the standard library should have a nice set of string handling features.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't that important a few decades ago, but support for networking is very important.

At the very least high-level stuff like HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Things that I use all the time is only the basic stuff like collections, network and I/O stuff. And I would expect that language to support it directly not by adding a library to it.

Answer (score 1):

A solid Math library helps quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

- Regular expressions
- Logging & other diagnostics
- Cryptography
- Collections (lists/maps/stacks/etc)